# Issue with tree node reference being overwritten in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am currently building a ScapeGoatTree for a project. However I am having an issue getting my rebuild function to properly take hold of the scapegoat node it is building. In the below code you will see inside the 'if( height >alpha height)' statement 2 more if statements. The first if statement compares my scapegoat node (which I know with current test data should be the static root.left node) and it correctly says they are equal. However when I try to change the Placeholder node(Which should hopefully be an object reference to root.left) it merely overwrites my placeholder node. So thus the second if statement does not fire off, but I need the returned value of my FindScapeGoat to be the node being edited.

I am not going to lie I have always been a bit bad at understanding the pass by reference and pass by value differences in languages, but I really do need to figure out how I can properly apply changes to root.left without needing a specific call to it (since the function will not always choose root.left as the scapegoat node I need a way to call various nodes in my tree rooted at a static location).

```
public static void Insert(int key) {
    height = dupflag = 0;
    root = insertHelp(root, key);
    if(dupflag == 0) MaxNodeCount++;    //If inserted value wasn't duplicate increase max node count
    double alphaHeight = ((Math.log(MaxNodeCount) / Math.log(1 / alpha)) + 1);
    if (height > alphaHeight){
        Node ToBeRebalanced = FindScapegoat(root, key);  // Find scapegoat node
        int sizeRoot = TreeSize(ToBeRebalanced, 0);
        if(ToBeRebalanced == root.left) System.out.println("Scapegoat node == root.left");
        ToBeRebalanced = RebuildTree(sizeRoot+1, ToBeRebalanced);
        if(ToBeRebalanced == root.left) System.out.println("Scapegoat node == root.left");
        Print(ToBeRebalanced);
        Print(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm like 90% of the way to understanding what you want. Is the method that's not doing what you want `RebuildTree`? If so, can you post the code? If not, can you try to clarify a little bit where things are going wrong? I understand the high-level problem you're having, but not where specifically that's manifesting in your code. Also, are `Placeholder` and `ToBeRebalanced` the same thing?

Comment: Essentially, I want this line:
"Node ToBeRebalanced = FindScapegoat(root, key); "

Or more importantly, the return of "FindScapeGoat(root, key); " to be the object that is edited. 

I know that in my current testing data FindScapeGoat will return 'root.left', and I set the placeholder Node ToBeRebalanced equal to 'root.left', however 3 lines down in the line: 
"ToBeRebalanced = RebuildTree(sizeRoot+1, ToBeRebalanced);"

The ToBeRebalanced holder node overwrites itself, instead of writing directly to root.left like I want it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the value/reference issue: non-primitive variables in Java behave (mostly, big caveat that's way out of scope for this answer) like pointers to memory locations. When you say `ToBeReplaced` you're changing the memory address that `ToBeReplaced` points to.

To your more specific issue, there are a couple of ways to handle this. The way that I would handle it would be to change the return from `FindScapegoat` to indicate whether the node is left or right. It seems like it's examining only the immediate children, so there's no need to return a reference to the node itself.

Something like this:

```
public enum Side {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
//...
Side ToBeRebalanced = FindScapegoat(root, key);  // Find scapegoat node
if (ToBeRebalanced == Side.Left){
  int sizeRoot = TreeSize(root.left, 0);
  root.left = RebuildTree(sizeRoot+1, root.left);
} else {
  int sizeRoot = TreeSize(root.right, 0);
  root.right = RebuildTree(sizeRoot+1, root.right);
}
```

You then could move the `TreeSize` call into the `RebuildTree` method to avoid the duplicated code.

Comment: More or less led me in right path of solution. Since my tree is more than height 2 I had to do a bit more then just call root.left / root.right there. But I was able to use the general idea to have FindScapegoat return parent to actual scapegoat node, and then have my references be to the returned nodes children which fixed my issues. Thank you very much!